# Bibliography does not load

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I cannot seem to get my references to load and show in my bibliography:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
 Here \cite{Franceschini.2008}
\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

I get the warnings that some references were undefined (Line 3 specifically to this one and Line 1 for the "general" warning).

`References` is my bibliography file, in the same folder as the LaTeX one. `Franceschini.2008` is one of the references in it.

I am running `PdfLaTeX + BiB(la)TeX(x2) + PdfLaTeX(x2) + View Pdf` in TeXMaker, and in other files with this setting the bibliography showed with the corrected citations.

Comment: please paste the error messages from bibtex, which should be in a file with .blg extension, also explain what command you mean by BiB(la)TeX(x2)

Comment: What exactly is `BiB(la)TeX(x2)` running? This needs to be `bibtex`.

Comment: I fixed it by running the sequence step-by-step and not the Quick Build so there was no issue with pdfLaTex and BiBLaTex. Thank you @daleif

Comment: @writingthesis, you are aware that Quick build in TeXMaker usually only runs pdflatex and preview the PDF. It does not automatically run bibtex (TeXStudio does, but AFAIK not TeXMaker). So the proper sequence is most likely F6, F11, F6, F1.

Comment: related: [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63875/579)